# R - How can we simulate a time series data that have local trend and cycle seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, seasonality

I want to simulate a time series in R, consisting a local trend and cycle seasonality.
The cycle seasonality component is:
[image]

I am using `datagen.stsm` to simulate a local trend but I am stuck in to add cycle seasonality component in the series.

```
ey <- rep(0,288) 
m <- stsm.model(model = "local-trend", y = ts(seq(288), frequency = 12), 
            pars = c("var1" = 1, "var2" = 0.05, "var3" = 0.0005), nopars = NULL)
ss <- char2numeric(m)
p <- datagen.stsm(n = 288, model = list(Z = ss$Z, T = ss$T, H = ss$H, Q = ss$Q), n0 = 20, freq = 12, old.version = T)$data
```

Comment: Hi.Welcome to Cross-Validated, can you explain what you mean exactly by "cycle seasonality"?

Comment: Hi @SkanderH.
What I mean is a seasonal component that can be modeled as a combination of six stochastic cycles. The single stochastic cycles has a trigonometric representation and are defined at the seasonal frequency `\lambda_j = (2*pi*j)/12` for j = 1,...,6.